# Visual Studio Web Test - Recording background requests

Tags: visual-studio, web-testing

I have a web test where my requirements need a handful of different polling requests to be going on in the background.  I have created a WebTestPlugin that looks for a certain context parameter to be set, and once it is, it kicks off a thread that just loops (every X seconds) firing off the configured request.

My issue is that this is not done in the context of the test, therefore the results (# of calls, duration, etc) is not part of the final report.

Is there a way to insert this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than starting your own thread to run the background requests I suggest using the facilities of the load test. That way the results will be properly recorded. Another reason is that the threading regime of a load test is not specified by Microsoft and adding your own thread may cause issues.

You could have one scenario for the main test. Another scenario has one or more simple tests for the background polling activity. These tests could be set with a "think time between iterations" or with "test mix based on user pace" to achieve the required background rate. To get the background web tests starting at the correct time start the test with a constant load of 0 (zero) users and use a load test plugin that adjusts the number of users whenever needed. The plugin writes the required number into `m_loadTest.Scenarios[N].CurrentLoad` for a suitable `N`. This would probably be done in the `Heartbeat` plugin but potentially could be in any load test plugin. If may be that the `TestFinished` plugin can better detect when the number of users should increase.

Comment: Hi Adrian, these scenarios, if you're using the terms from a VS web test, means I can only run one at a time, right?  Meaning I either run the "main test" or the "background polling" test.  What I need is to background poll while simultaneously running the main thread, without one blocking the other.

Comment: No. I am suggesting scenarios of load tests. All the scenarios in a load test run at the same time. (Only one of the "run settings" can run at a time.) One use of scenarios is for a shopping site where one scenario simulates many customers and another simulates a small number of shop staff.  Both need to be active but have different use patterns.

Comment: Gotchya. Ok that makes sense.  My issue now is that my "heartbeat" request needs to have a unique and current user ID that is received from the web api during on scenario and that needs to be accessible from the "heartbeat" scenario. Is it possible create a global list of strings that my heartbeat scenario can look at and if there is a new entry it just spawns a new user and fires the test?

Comment: It is a bit "ugly", but you could use a `static` member of some convenient `class`.

Comment: For a web test, ugly will do.  Thank you Adrian!  Your help has been amazing